# How to change the title of a legend in heatmap( )?

Tags: r, heatmap

In ggplot2 to change a legend title you simply add + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title")). But how do I do the same thing while using the Heatmap() function? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hip6.jpg) is the heatmap I am attempting to label. Please tell me if you need any other information! (The title I would like to change is matrix_1

Code:

```
Heatmap(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2.ris.mat2, row_names_side = "left",     
row_dend_side = "left", row_names_gp = gpar(cex=fontsize), 
column_names_gp = gpar(cex=fontsize), )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to edit the "name" argument. So for example:

```
Heatmap(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2.ris.mat2, row_names_side = "left",     
row_dend_side = "left", row_names_gp = gpar(cex=fontsize), 
column_names_gp = gpar(cex=fontsize), name="something else then matrix_1")
```

By the way, it would be nice to give information about the package you are using.